# What am I Doing wrong. Google kickstart 2020

Tags: python, algorithm

this the question.

> Ron read a book about boring numbers. According to the book, a positive number is called boring if all of the digits at even positions in the number are even and all of the digits at odd positions are odd. The digits are enumerated from left to right starting from 1. For example, the number 1478 is boring as the odd positions include the digits {1, 7} which are odd and even positions include the digits {4, 8} which are even.

> Given two numbers L and R, Ron wants to count how many numbers in the range [L, R] (L and R inclusive) are boring. Ron is unable to solve the problem, hence he needs your help.
> Input
> The first line of the input gives the number of test cases, T. T test cases follow. Each test case consists of a single line with two numbers L and R.

> Output
> For each test case, output one line containing Case #x: y, where x is the test case number (starting from 1) and y is the count of boring numbers.

> Sample
> 3
> 5 15              Case #1: 6
> 120 125           Case #2: 3
> 779 783           Case #3: 2

And this is the result which I have written.

```
t = int(input())

for case in range(1, t+1):
    total_number = 0
    numbers = []
    l, r = map(int, input().split())
    for number in range(l, r+1):
        answer = False
        for x in range(len(str(number))):
            position = x+1
            pos_num = int(str(number)[x])
            if ((position%2 == 0) and (pos_num%2 == 0)) or ((position%2 ==1) and (position%2 == 1)):
                answer = True
            else:
                answer = False
        if answer == True:
            numbers.append(number)
            total_number += 1

    print(f"Case #{case}: {total_number}")
```

I am running this and getting the wrong results. Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are your results? Why do you think they fail?

Comment: ```if ((position%2 == 0) and (pos_num%2 == 0)) or ((position%2 ==1) and (position%2 == 1))``` is causing incorrect results. Read about operator chaining

Comment: Thanks for helping out guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry guys, I got the answer. This is the answer but if anyone can suggest a more efficient answer then, you are most welcome!

```
t = int(input())

for case in range(1, t + 1):
    total_number = 0
    numbers = []
    l, r = map(int, input().split())
    for number in range(l, r + 1):
        answer = []
        lst_number = list(str(number))
        for x in range(len(lst_number)):
            position = x + 1
            pos_num = int(lst_number[x])
            if ((position % 2 == 0) and (pos_num % 2 == 0)) or ((position % 2 == 1) and (pos_num % 2 == 1)):
                answer.append(1)
            else:
                answer.append(0)
        if 0 not in answer:
            numbers.append(number)
            total_number += 1

    print(f"Case #{case}: {total_number}")
```